# How to manually deploy on a shared hosting?

Tags: 9, deployment

In my shared hosting: no git, no composer, no root folder settings. Only the folder "public_html". And my Drupal files: vendor, web, composer.json, composer.lock.

How should I put it all in public folder? What should I change? In settings.php I've already written my new db settings, but this is not enough.

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question. The only thing you can do in this case is ftp or rsync it, from CI or not.

Comment: @Kevin it's not about "how to upload", but "how to structure and which settings to apply". There is no index.php in root folder, and it's not gonna work in shared hosting. So I need to change all folder structure.

Comment: Changing the folder structure is not a great idea, it will make updating awkward. Better to change the web server config to serve from the web or docroot subfolder instead. Any decent hosting provider will be able to give you instructions on how to do that on their infrastructure. Or even better they’ll be able to tell you how to store files outside the web root and you’ll just be able to serve it like a normal Drupal site

Comment: @Clive, unfortunately, our hosting provider is not decent. Support said it's not their problem. But client loves that hosting, has 10 sites on it and doesn't want to change provider. So I had to change structure with composer on localhost and put all the folders right in the root directory.